# why I'm getting error in executing my C++ code

Tags: c++, mingw

I have installed MinGW 3 times and I've also added path in env. variable but whenever I try to run a code in CodeLight it just gives me the following error:

> mingw-32-make.exe: *** [ALL] Error 2

In MinGW installation tutorials there are .exe files in the bin folder but I don't have any .exe file in the bin folder inside MinGW. I've tried installing it 3 and very carefully.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is the content of Makefile that you are using and how do you run it? Is this the only error message or do you get something else before that?

Comment: There is a typo: it's not `mingw-32-make.exe` but `mingw32-make.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the compiler and build tools are properly configured in the IDE (CodeLight).

Installing MinGW by itself doesn't tell CodeLight were to find it.

There is a standalone MinGW-w64 personal build available at http://winlibs.com/ that doesn't need installation, just unzip it. On the site there is an explanation on he wot configure Code::Blocks IDE to use this compiler. The steps should be pretty similar in CodeLight.